# Laravel routes, form won't submit data into the database

Tags: laravel

beginner trying to submit a basic form into the database using laravel. I know I should be using 'get' to display the registerform but when I do that I get the 'methodnotallowedhttpexception error.

Currently when I enter data into the form and press submit it just refreshes the page. Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks

web.php

```
Route::post('registerForm', 'AuthController@viewregisterForm');

Route::post('registerUser', 'AuthController@registerUser');
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

//use App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
function viewregisterForm()
{
     return view('register/registerForm');
}
function registerUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'dateofbirth' =>'required',
    ]);
    //create a Film object
    $user = new $User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = $request->password;
    $user->dateofbirth = $request->dateofbirth;
    $user->role = 1;

    $user->save();
    return redirect('all');
}
}

?>
```

registerForm.blade

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Register user')
@section('content')

<form action="{{url('registerForm')}}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<h1>Register user</h1>
<div>
<label for="title">Enter name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</div>

<div>
`enter code here`<label for="title">Enter email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
</div>

<div>
<label for="title">Enter password</label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password">

<label for="title">Enter date of birth</label>
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
</div>



<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Add User">
</form>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the action of your form submit

from

```
<form action="{{ url('registerForm') }}" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ route('register-user') }}" method="POST">
```

and change the route from

```
Route::post('registerUser', 'AuthController@registerUser');
```

to

```
Route::post('registerUser', ['as' => 'register-user', 'uses' => 'AuthController@registerUser']);
```

Comment: Hi, once i try submit the form I get the 'NotFoundHttpException' error, it also redirects me to the (http://localhost/laravel-master/public/registerUser) URL

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your routes to this:

```
Route::get('registerForm', 'AuthController@viewregisterForm');

Route::post('registerForm', 'AuthController@registerUser');
```